# Genymotion no sound after virtualbox update

Tags: sound, virtualbox, alsa, debug, genymotion

I have an old android virtual machine on Genymotion. I use it regularly and I have my apps on it.

After a recent virtualbox update the audio had issues. Now I almost can't hear any sound. *I can hear part of the audio being played every about 3 seconds. Just a "segment" of sound.*

How do I fix this or how do I debug?

Comment: Thank you so much for shared info. It helps a lot. Just downgrade version of VB to 5.0.26 - and you will get working sound.